# Laravel liveware - input is not getting date value

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

i'm new with livewire, i have a issue with my form, the date value input is not showing well in the field date. Can you help me to understand why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Livewire sets data from its PHP component, and syncs the frontend on each request. This means that any `value=""` you set on an input with `wire:model` on it, won't work. Livewire will overwrite the value with what it has on its property in the backend.

So, since you have `wire:model="date_user_birth"`, that means that you have to set the value of `$this->date_user_birth` in the PHP class.

```php
class MyClass extends Component 
{
    public $date_user_birth;

    public function mount() 
    {
        $this->date_user_birth = '08-09-2021';
    }

}
```